# Where did org.jboss.resteasy.spi.validation.ValidateRequest go?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm in process of upgrading resteasy from v2.3.5 to 3.0.26 and have problem with

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.validation.ValidateRequest
```

This class (annotation) is no longer available in any of the resteasy-related jars I have in my CP.

Where did this class go? Is there any substitute?